# How can I have object.model_set two foreign keys to the same model in Django?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, django-rest-framework

Here is my code

```py
from django.db.models import Models
class ChatRoom(Models.model):
    room_member_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, related_name="member_1", on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    room_member_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, related_name="member_2", on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
```

According to feature the `User` object could be `room_member_1` and `room_member_2`. If one of the user object's has 5 `ChatRoom` then we can get user's chat rooms using following query like `user_object.member_1` or `user_object.member_2`

Now i want to get `user_object` all chat room using one query without `ChatRoom.objects.filter(Q(room_member_1=user_object)|Q(room_member_2=user_object))` query.
Is it possible ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you could do that by using a custom manager for the `ChatRoom` model, like that:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db.models import Q

class ChatRoomManager(models.Manager):
    def get_user_chatrooms(self, user):
        return self.filter(Q(room_member_1=user) | Q(room_member_2=user))
```

Next a custom manager:

```
from django.db.models import Model
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class ChatRoom(Model):
    room_member_1 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, related_name="member_1", on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )
    room_member_2 = models.ForeignKey(
        User, null=True, related_name="member_2", on_delete=models.SET_NULL
    )

    objects = ChatRoomManager()
```

Now we will have all chat rooms for a specific user using the custom manager method like this:

```
user_chatrooms = ChatRoom.objects.get_user_chatrooms(user_object)
```